# What is the quickest way to cumulatively add Gaussians together?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, computer-vision, heatmap

**Goal:**
Given a list of a few hundred 2D coordinate predictions, I want to find the most likely coordinate to contain the label. I also have a coarse prediction of how likely each 8x8 pixel area of the image contains the landmark. The resolution of the image is 512x512.

**Method:**
(Using Python) I represent every prediction as a small Gaussian blob on a single 2D image, that add cumulatively. The mean of the Gaussian blob is the predicted coordinate with a std of 1.

If two points are close to one another I want their Gaussian values to cumulatively add so that area has a higher activation. I want to pick the pixel with the highest activation as the final prediction. Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image: Each point is represented as a small Gaussian blob, that adds cumulatively.]

**Problem:**

Currently, I am generating a Gaussian for each point and adding it onto the mapping, but this is really slow. Is there a mathematically equivalent way to do this that is much faster? e.g. map just the pixel of each prediction onto an image and then apply some function (smoothing?) to it?

Or is there something more clever I can do to achieve the same goal of selecting the most likely final prediction given the list of predictions? Since the pixel values are cumulative, the value of the peak pixel contains some information about how "confident" the final prediction might be, so I wish to preserve something like this. I also want to use the coarse likelihood information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is the 2-d convolution of your image with a Gaussian bump. Convolution is typically implemented via FFT so it scales like n log(n) instead of n^2 where n is the number of elements. I guess n = m^2 where the image is m by m pixels.

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks for the response. Is there an efficient way to generate a gaussian bump? For each prediction I am generating a 512x512 Gaussian image where obviously only a tiny part of that contains the "gaussian bump" and then adding them cumulatively. This inefficient generation is what is making it so slow. Please could you offer a little more detail about what you mean, it seems really promising! Thank you.

Comment: @RobertDodier I solved it. I plotted each point cumulatively as a pixel and then applied a Gaussian blur and mathematically equivalent :).

Comment: Sounds good. Yes, Gaussian blur is exactly the same.

Comment: @RobertDodier ah good to know. thanks for the help.

Comment: The method of writing single pixels and then apply a Gaussian smoothing only works if all coordinates are integer. If you want higher precision you need to draw the Gaussians directly. You can use this one: https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/group__generation__drawing.html#gad34c358ca86e9d526eeab0a8cd62b44f (`pip install diplib`).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the insight. Fortunately, my coordinates are integer but I will remember for next time. I have actually posted another question from the next step in this pipeline if you could spare your expertise. Thanks :)